# How to compute conditionals (IF) in a column cell in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Not sure how to compute IF conditionals on a dataframe as you would do in a standard python code.

I have the following df:

[image: Data Frame]

The values in 'Label' corresponds to the maximum value from each row. As an example, row (0) the maximum value corresponds to NO_2.

I want to replace the value in 'Label' based on the following chart:

[image: ICA]

So for example, for row (0) the 'Label' value corresponds to NO_2 as mentioned before, so checking the chart the value of 67.120003 falls into the range of 40-100 for NO_2, hence I would like to replace the 'Label' value for row (0) with 2.

Here is a piece od data (*Note: I'm modiying it a bit in order to obtain variablility for maximum values for each contaminant for the sake of an example):

```
            date        O_3     PM25        PM10        CO      SO_2         NO_2       Label
0   2001-01-01 01:00:00 7.86    12.505127   32.349998   0.45    26.459999   67.120003   67.120003
1   2001-01-01 02:00:00 7.21    12.505127   40.709999   0.48    20.879999   70.620003   70.620003
2   2001-01-01 03:00:00 7.11    12.505127   50.209999   0.41    21.580000   72.629997   72.629997
3   2001-01-01 04:00:00 7.14    12.505127   54.880001   0.51    19.270000   75.029999   75.029999
4   2001-01-01 05:00:00 8.46    12.505127   42.340000   0.19    13.640000   66.589996   66.589996
5   2018-04-30 20:00:00 63.00   200.000000  2.000000    0.30    4.000000    58.000000   200.000000
6   2018-04-30 21:00:00 49.00   400.000000  5.000000    0.30    4.000000    65.000000   400.000000
7   2018-04-30 22:00:00 49.00   3.000000    125.000000  0.30    4.000000    58.000000   125.000000
8   2018-04-30 23:00:00 48.00   7.000000    7.000000    0.30    4.000000    52.000000   52.000000
9   2018-05-01 00:00:00 52.00   4.000000    6.000000    0.30    4.000000    43.000000   52.000000
```

So in order to get the maximum value from each row, what I'm doing is:

```
# Getting max values from each contaminant on each row
max_value = final_df.max(axis=1)
```

And in order to obtain the maximum value column name:

```
# Obtaining maximum value column name for each row
label_max_colName = final_df.eq(final_df.max(1), 
axis=0).dot(final_df.columns)
```

I have followed one of the proposed solutions from @TH14 which is:

```
for index, val in final_df[[x for x in final_df.columns if x != 'date']].iterrows():
    max_column = np.argmax(val)
    max_column_val = np.max(val)

    if max_column == "O_3":
        if max_column_val <= 80:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 80 < max_column_val < 120:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 120 < max_column_val < 180:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 180 < max_column_val < 240:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 240 < max_column_val < 600:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == "NO_2":
        if max_column_val <= 40:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 40 < max_column_val < 100:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 100 < max_column_val < 200:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 200 < max_column_val < 400:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 400 < max_column_val < 1000:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == "SO_2":
        if max_column_val <= 100:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 40 < max_column_val < 200:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 100 < max_column_val < 350:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 200 < max_column_val < 500:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 400 < max_column_val < 1250:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == "PM10":
        if max_column_val <= 20:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 40 < max_column_val < 35:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 100 < max_column_val < 50:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 200 < max_column_val < 100:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 400 < max_column_val < 1200:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == "PM25":
        if max_column_val <= 10:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 40 < max_column_val < 20:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 100 < max_column_val < 25:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 200 < max_column_val < 50:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 400 < max_column_val < 800:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5
```

But does not seem to change anything in the 'Label' column:

[image: Result of computed Label column df]

Comment: kindly do not post images of the data, please provide a textual sample of your data frame so a solution can be provided. Your attempt (in pusedo code) would also be highly appreciated

Comment: you need to remove .head() in the first line and fix the indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only added the if else conditions for two columns, but you get the idea.

```
df['Label'] = df.max(axis=1)


for index, val in final_df[[x for x in final_df.columns if x != 'date']].iterrows():
    max_column = np.argmax(val)
    max_column_val = np.max(val)

    if max_column == "O_3":
        if max_column_val <= 80:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 80 < max_column_val < 120:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 120 < max_column_val < 180:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 180 < max_column_val < 240:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 240 < max_column_val < 600:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == "NO_2":
        if max_column_val <= 40:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 40 < max_column_val < 100:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 100 < max_column_val < 200:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 200 < max_column_val < 400:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 400 < max_column_val < 1000:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == "SO_2":
        if max_column_val <= 100:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 40 < max_column_val < 200:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 100 < max_column_val < 350:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 200 < max_column_val < 500:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 400 < max_column_val < 1250:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == "PM10":
        if max_column_val <= 20:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 40 < max_column_val < 35:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 100 < max_column_val < 50:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 200 < max_column_val < 100:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 400 < max_column_val < 1200:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5

    if max_column == "PM25":
        if max_column_val <= 10:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 1

        if 40 < max_column_val < 20:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 2

        if 100 < max_column_val < 25:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 3

        if 200 < max_column_val < 50:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 4

        if 400 < max_column_val < 800:
            final_df.at[index, 'Label'] = 5
```

You were getting that error with orKach's solution because you were iterating over the date column.

Output:

```
       date                O_3         PM25        PM10      CO    SO_2        NO_2        Label
0   2001-01-01  01:00:00    7.86    12.505127   32.349998   0.45    26.459999   67.120003   2.0
1   2001-01-01  02:00:00    7.21    12.505127   40.709999   0.48    20.879999   70.620003   2.0
2   2001-01-01  03:00:00    7.11    12.505127   50.209999   0.41    21.580000   72.629997   2.0
3   2001-01-01  04:00:00    7.14    12.505127   54.880001   0.51    19.270000   75.029999   2.0
4   2001-01-01  05:00:00    8.46    12.505127   42.340000   0.19    13.640000   66.589996   2.0
5   2018-04-30  20:00:00    63.00   200.000000  2.000000    0.30    4.000000    58.000000   200.0
6   2018-04-30  21:00:00    49.00   400.000000  5.000000    0.30    4.000000    65.000000   400.0
7   2018-04-30  22:00:00    49.00   3.000000    125.000000  0.30    4.000000    58.000000   125.0
8   2018-04-30  23:00:00    48.00   7.000000    7.000000    0.30    4.000000    52.000000   2.0
9   2018-05-01  00:00:00    52.00   4.000000    6.000000    0.30    4.000000    43.000000   1.0
```

Comment: I have completed your proposed code but does not reflect the expected output, is not changing anything in the 'Label' column. Thanks for the advise on the date column, I realised that after reading a few posts.

Comment: it's not supposed to update the values in the "Label" column, its creating a new column "pollutant_ix_level".

Comment: I tried keeping it as a new column but even though did not add it to the df

Comment: Finally I've been able to pull it out. The problem is that max_column = np.argmax(val) is returning an integer ( column position) reason why it was not printing the column Label correctly. All I've done is change each pollutant string for its  column position value.

Comment: that's odd. on my end max_column = np.argmax(val) returns the column name

for index, val in final_df[[x for x in final_df.columns if x != 'date']].iterrows():
    max_column = np.argmax(val)
    max_column_val = np.max(val)
    print(max_column)
Output:
NO_2
NO_2
NO_2
NO_2
NO_2
PM25
PM25
PM10
NO_2
O_3

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define a function which receives the pollutant and the concentration level and returns the label number like so:

```
def get_pollution_label(pollutant, concentration):
    if pollutant == 'o_3':
        if 0 < con < 80:
            return 1
    .
    .
    .
```

After writing this function, which should just be a series of 'if-else's corresponding to the table, you can iterate over the rows and do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    df['Label'] = get_pollution_label(df.columns[np.argmax(row)], np.max(row))
```

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but I'm getting the following error which I don't quite understand, since all column values are floats: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have both of your tables as dataframes

```
data_df = 
     O_3   PM25  ...  ...
0   7.86    ...
1    ...         ... 
2    ...              ...
```

and

```
category_df = 
        1    2    3
O_3    80  120  ...
NO2    40  ...  
...   ...       ...
```

you can also identify the maximum values and corresponding column via `df.max(axis=1)` and `df.idxmax(axis=1)` respectively. Also, `import numpy as np` to use the `np.where(condition)` function for comparison purposes and identify the maximum label with `np.max()`.

```
max_df = pd.DataFrame(my_df.max(axis=1).values, index=my_df.idxmax(axis=1))
labels = []
for idx, row in max_df.iterrows():
    labels.append(np.max(np.where(row.values[0] < category_df.loc[idx])))
data_df["Label"] = pd.Series(labels)
```